# Retrieve files with jQuery and transcrypt

Tags: jquery, file, transcrypt

I am having problems to get jQuery to work with transcrypt. Here is my code. I would like to retrieve a file with load and put it into a variable. The function read_file works fine and displays the var in a div element. But the other two functions do not work as expected: read_hidden_var only works after clicking it a 2nd time and read_file_var does not work at all producing an error saying: TypeError $.py_get is not a function.

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

__pragma__ ('alias', 'S', '$')

class TestSystem:

    def read_file(self):
        S("#demo").load("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bunkahle/Transcrypt-Examples/master/README.md")

    def read_hidden_var(self):
        document.getElementById('hidden_text').style.display='block'
        S("#hidden_text").load("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bunkahle/Transcrypt-Examples/master/README.md")
        console.log(S("#hidden_text").html())
        self.file_content = S("#hidden_text").html()
        S("#hidden_text").html("")
        document.getElementById('hidden_text').style.display='none'
        alert(self.file_content)

    def read_file_var(self):
        S.get("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bunkahle/Transcrypt-Examples/master/README.md", self.get_filecontent)

    def get_filecontent(self, response):
        self.file_content = response
        alert(self.file_content)

testSystem = TestSystem()
```

and the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="__javascript__/read_file2.js"; charset="UTF-8"></script>
    <title>Read File</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
        <h1>Read a file!</h1>
        <p id="p1" class="para1">Read a file!</p>
      <button id="button1" onclick="$(document).ready(read_file2.testSystem.read_file)">Click for retrieving text file</button><br><br>
      <button id="button1" onclick="$(document).ready(read_file2.testSystem.read_file_var)">Click for retrieving text file into var</button><br><br>
      <button id="button1" onclick="$(document).ready(read_file2.testSystem.read_hidden_var)">Click for retrieving text file into hidden paragraph</button><br><br>
      <p id="demo"></p>
      <p id="hidden_text"></p>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The "py_get is not a function" report is caused by aliasing.
The word `get` has a special meaning in Python so it's by default aliased to `py_get`, which in this context doesn't exist.
You can either unalias `get` or use `js_get`, since that is aliased to `get`.
Similar options are there for all aliases, as can be seen in the list of predefined aliases at:

http://www.transcrypt.org/docs/html/special_facilities.html#pragma-alias

In the modified code below I've used `js_get`, since it has least impact.
(To find modifications, search for `!!!`)

The double click problem is harder to tackle. *I've replaced the code involved in  that by pure JavaScript and the problem remains.* So I strongly suspect (but am not 100% sure) that this is something not specifically tied to Transcrypt, but to the underlying program logic. But I can't currently pinpoint it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

__pragma__ ('alias', 'S', '$')

class TestSystem:

    def read_file(self):
        S("#demo").load("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bunkahle/Transcrypt-Examples/master/README.md")

    def read_hidden_var(self):
        # !!! Literally inserted JavaScript does not solve the second problem,
        # so probably this isn't specific to Transcrypt
        __pragma__ ('js', '{}', '''
            console.log ("BEGIN read_hidden_var");
            document.getElementById("hidden_text").style.display="block";
            $("#hidden_text").load("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bunkahle/Transcrypt-Examples/master/README.md");
            console.log($("#hidden_text").html());
            self.file_content = $("#hidden_text").html();
            $("#hidden_text").html("");
            document.getElementById("hidden_text").style.display="none";
            alert(self.file_content);
            console.log ("END read_hidden_var");
        ''')

    def read_file_var(self):
        # !!! Using js_get solves the first problem
        S.js_get("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bunkahle/Transcrypt-Examples/master/README.md", self.get_filecontent)

    def get_filecontent(self, response):
        self.file_content = response
        alert(self.file_content)

testSystem = TestSystem()
```